# Strange Math 2.1

Tags: mathematics

Thanks so much for helping me fix my grades in math, but I need your help again. I thought my homework would be easy. But then my teacher gave me some sample problems, and I don't understand them. Could you help me figure it out, and then solve the last problem?

> 1 + 1 = 10
> 4 * 3 = 14
> 87 - 23 = 27
> 11 + 9 = 14
> 6 - 15 = 15
> 21 * 0 = ?

Comment: You are certain there are no typos, correct?

Comment: I just checked, and I fixed the few there were. I sincerely apologize for my mistakes. I hope it didn't hinder your solving process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to the last question is:

> 18!

We see the following pattern:

> ONE PLUS ONE = 10 characters
>  FOUR TIMES THREE = 14 characters
>  EIGHTY SEVEN MINUS TWENTYTHREE = 27 characters
>  ELEVEN PLUS NINE = 14 characters
>  SIX MINUS FIFTEEN =  15 characters
>  TWENTYONE TIMES ZERO = **18 characters**

Comment: Congratulations! : )